# AttributeError: 'LGEOS360' object has no attribute 'GEOSMinimumClearance'

Tags: python, geopandas

Since the latest Mac update I am having issues importing GeoPandas. When I import it, I get the following error.

*AttributeError: 'LGEOS360' object has no attribute 'GEOSMinimumClearance'*

Have tried updating shapely but that did not solve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling GeoPandas and its dependencies in a new environment? There might be broken links now due to the OS update.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately that did not resolve it

Comment: Can you report the issue? If you used `conda-forge` here - https://github.com/conda-forge/geopandas-feedstock/issues and if you did not here - https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues.

Comment: Hey, I originally did pip install. Then after reading the above GitHub source you mentioned, I tried again with condo-forge. Neither worked. I ended up completely uninstalling Anaconda and then reinstalling and that fixed the issue. Thanks for your help!